# How to adjust the height of TextView with layout_height="wrap_content"

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

TextView with single line or multi line
so i set layout_height="wrap_content"
When the TextView is 3 more lines, it work well

[image: Mutilines TextView]

but it not work well in single line

[image: SingleLine TextView]

Why the single line TextView's height is bigger than the text height?

Here is my TextView code

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_item_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#55000000"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/card_item_title1"
        android:layout_below="@id/card_item_title1_group"
        />
```

Comment: it works well means what exactly ??

Comment: it means the TextView's height(Gray background) is just adjust the string height